# May I know why this program show syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("welcome to the rollercoast!")
height=int(input("what is your height in CM?"))
bill = 0
if height >= 120:
  print("you can ride the rollercoaster")
  age=int(input("what is your age ?"))
  if age < 12:
    bill = 5$
    print("please pay bill!")
  elif age <= 18:
    bill = 7$
    print("please pay bill !")
  else:
    bill = 12$
    print("please pay 12$")
   what_photo=input("do you want take a photo? Y or N ") 
  if what_photo == "y"
    bill += 3
    print(f"your final bill is {bill}")
else:
  print("sorry,you have to grow taller before you can ride")
```

Please explain to me why it is showing a syntax error

i am expecting what is total bill will come after completing all step at the end.

Comment: As the error points out, `5$` isn't a valid Python syntax.  Get rid of the $.  You can put it in the *display* when you print the bill.  Note for future *add* the error message to the question.

Answer (score 0):

the lines where you define bill=5$ or 7$ give a syntax error because while 5 is an integer, $ is not a numerical character, thus 5$ becomes a string. What you can do instead is concatenate str(bill) with '$'